# Insert text if image doesn't exist Aspose Mail Merge

Tags: c#, mailmerge, aspose.words

I'm working on inserting images and here is my code:

```
void IFieldMergingCallback.ImageFieldMerging(ImageFieldMergingArgs e)
{
    if (this.mBuilder == null)
        this.mBuilder = new DocumentBuilder(e.Document);

    string filename = GetFilePath();
    if (!File.Exists(filename))
    {
        //todo insert text "<Image not found>" instead image
        this.mBuilder.MoveToField(e.Field, false);
        this.mBuilder.Write("<Image not found>");
        e.ImageFileName = string.Empty;
        return;
    }

    e.ImageFileName = filename;
}
```

And I want to insert text `"<Image not found>"` if image doesn't exist. But this code throws error `Cannot load image from field '...'. The field contains data in unsupported format. Could not find file`.

What should I insert to fix my bug?

Comment: Please share complete source code (without compilation errors) that helps us to reproduce your problem on our end. Please also provide the template document you are getting this problem with. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solve my problem. I just need to remove field into my `if` statement:

```
this.mBuilder.MoveToField(e.Field, false);
this.mBuilder.Write("<Image not found>");
e.Field.Remove();
return;
```